# How to group rows, select one by a number - ext with other columns - in SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I had an issue with writing a query that would gather groups in a column, and then select one of them by a number.
A good person (@sstan) gave me this:

```
select your_col
  from (select your_col,
               row_number() over (order by your_col) as rn
          from your_table
         group by your_col)
 where rn = 2
```

And it works. However, it appears that my query needs to consider other columns. For now, it looks like this:

```
select MAINCOL, sum(some_col+other_col) as together_col, count(another_col)

from my_table

where date_col >= next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 14
and date_col < next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 7

group by  MAINCOL, other_col, together_col
order by MAINCOL
```

So the challenge is to extend the upper query with what is below. Although I couldn't make it work, it seems simple..

Comment: can you elaborate what you want to achieve using that query?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with Inner table alias

```
SELECT your_col,rn.your_col,rn.your_col2,rn.your_col3
FROM(select your_col,your_col2,your_col3,row_number() over (order by your_col) 
      from your_table group by your_col)as rn where rn = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Chintan7027 . It's almost good :) Returns:

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 51

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
With help of Stack, of course.

```
select t.*
from (select MAINCOL, col1, col2, col3, col4, DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY MAINCOL) GROUPID
      from tab_1
      group by MAINCOL, col1, col2
     ) t
where GROUPID = 1;
```